# rails enum, load enum values based on condition is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

lets say i have a model with enum like this :

```
class Apt < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum apt_status: [ :draft, :publish, :unpublish, :waiting ]

end
```

and in my controller i load my enum like this :

```
@apt_statuses = Apt.apt_statuses
```

it's working fine, but what if i want to load my enum values based on user role? 
so lets say if i am an admin i want to load all my enum values, and if i am not an admin, i only display 3 enum values

> ":draft, :unpublish, :waiting"

is it possible? please suggest. many thanks.

btw here is my controller, i really have no idea how to fill my

> @apt_statuses

in else condition

```
       ishaveprivilage = Usermaster.joins(:rolemasters, :rolemasters).where(id: @current_user.id, rolemasters: {name: "Super Admin"})


   if ishaveprivilage
        @apt_statuses = Apt.apt_statuses
   else

   end
```

i use my enum in view like this :

```
 <%= f.select :apt_status, options_for_select(@apt_statuses.collect { |s| [s[0].humanize, s[0]] }, selected: @apt.apt_status), {} , class: "form-control" %>
```

error trace :

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Apts#new
Showing C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/urbanace/urbanacecode/app/views/admin/apts/_form.html.erb where line #134 raised:

undefined method `humanize' for :draft:Symbol
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/admin/apts/new.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/urbanace/urbanacecode

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/admin/apts/_form.html.erb:134:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_admin_apts__form_html_erb___8345113_90629556'
app/views/admin/apts/_form.html.erb:134:in `each'
app/views/admin/apts/_form.html.erb:134:in `collect'
app/views/admin/apts/_form.html.erb:134:in `block in _app_views_admin_apts__form_html_erb___8345113_90629556'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
app/views/admin/apts/_form.html.erb:57:in `_app_views_admin_apts__form_html_erb___8345113_90629556'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:51:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
app/views/admin/apts/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_admin_apts_new_html_erb__809278863_96977256'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in `render_with_remotipart'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.7) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
_csrf_token: "DK6t1OuVBdMWZLihVgktZFIQSo7gX3qt5Iq5ZHyA7lM="
session_id: "2391dc6faaafcd52ee1815ccbe115daf"
user_id: 7
Toggle env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=0"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
Response

Headers:

None
x
>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would solve this like so:

```
class Apt < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:draft, :publish, :unpublish, :waiting]

  def self.user_specific_statuses(user)
    if user.admin? # define a method in your user model which defines this.
      Apt.statuses
    else
      Apt.statuses.reject { |k, v| k == "publish" } # => all except publish
    end
  end
end
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
Apt.user_specific_statuses(admin_user) # => all statuses
Apt.user_specific_statuses(normal_user) # => only draft, unpublish, waiting
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your suggestion, i have a question thought, i read from this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html that said if i use 2 enum with the same values, in my case : "draft, unpublish, waiting" have to use prefix things? btw i also figured a workaround for my case, which one is  a better approach.

Comment: i tried your yours suggestion, caused an error in view, undefined method `humanize' for :draft:Symbol

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace to your question?

Comment: updated my question with view usage, and error trace

Comment: it worked, "reject" does the trick, but i guess it's almost the same approach like my answer, the only different is my approach take place in controller, while yours take place in model, which is more effective in case i want to use this model multiple times. upvoted. thanks.

Comment: (you can accept this as the answer to close this question)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know is this an ideal way to do this or not but i solved it with this approach :

i changed my model enum definition to this :

model :   `enum apt_status: { draft:0, publish:1, unpublish:2, waiting:3 }`

and in my controller i did this :

```
 ishaveprivilage = Usermaster.joins(:rolemasters, :rolemasters).where(id: @current_user.id, rolemasters: {name: "Super Admin"})

          if !ishaveprivilage.blank?    

                @apt_statuses = Apt.apt_statuses
          else
                temp = Apt.apt_statuses.reject { |k,v| v == 1 } #remove Publish option for non super admin
                @apt_statuses = temp
          end
```

if you guys have a better approach, please advise.